# git: 'aws.push' is not a git command when trying to push a repository to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk on Mac

Tags: macos, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following setup:

- Mac OS X 10.10
- Python 2.7

I did the following steps

1. AWS EB Console Tools added to my path

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/amazon-eb/eb/linux/python2.7/
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
   export AWS_SECRET_KEY=xxx
   export AWS_CREDENTIALS_PATH=~/.aws/credentials
   ```
2. AWS Credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`

   ```
   [default]
   AWSAccessKeyId=xxx
   AWSSecretKey=xxx
   ```
3. Created a project with `.elasticbeanstalk/config` file

   ```
   [global]
   ApplicationName=Oselot Wordpress Blog
   DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   EnvironmentName=oselotWordpressBlog-env
   Region=us-east-1
   ```
4. When I try to run `eb status` it asks me for my credentials (not sure why....). So I enter them. Seems like it works

   ```
   Anatoliys-MBP:oselot-blog toli$ eb status
   To get your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, 
     visit "https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials".
   Enter your AWS Access Key ID: xxx
   Enter your AWS Secret Access Key: xxx
   URL     : xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com
   Status      : Ready
   Health      : Green

   RDS Database: AWSEBRDSDatabase | xxx.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
   ```
5. I run `git aws.push` and I get error:

   ```
   git: 'aws.push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I ran `eb init` which ended up asking me a lot of questions that I already set up in the Beanstalk GUI. I don't understand why this is necessary...

```
Anatoliys-MBP:oselot-blog toli$ eb init

To get your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, 
  visit "https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials".
Enter your AWS Access Key ID: xxx
Enter your AWS Secret Access Key: xxx
Select an AWS Elastic Beanstalk service region (current value is "US East (Virginia)").
Available service regions are:
1) US East (Virginia)
2) US West (Oregon)
3) US West (North California)
4) EU West (Ireland)
5) Asia Pacific (Singapore)
6) Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
7) Asia Pacific (Sydney)
8) South America (Sao Paulo)
Select (1 to 8): 1
Enter an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application name (current value is "Oselot Wordpress Blog"): 
Enter an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment name (current value is "oselotWordpressBlog-env"): 
Select an environment tier.
Available environment tiers are:
1) WebServer::Standard::1.0
2) Worker::SQS/HTTP::1.0
Select (1 to 2): 1
Select a solution stack.
Available solution stacks are:
1) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.5
2) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.5
3) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.4
4) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.4
5) 32bit Amazon Linux running PHP 5.3
6) 64bit Amazon Linux running PHP 5.3
7) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Node.js
8) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Node.js
9) 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5
10) 64bit Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8
11) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
12) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
13) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 6
14) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 6
15) 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7
16) 64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7
17) 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6
18) 64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6
19) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python 2.7
20) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python 2.7
21) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python
22) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python
23) 32bit Amazon Linux running Python
24) 64bit Amazon Linux running Python
25) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)
26) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)
27) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 1.9.3
28) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 1.9.3
29) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.02 v1.0.1 running Ruby 1.8.7
30) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.02 v1.0.1 running Ruby 1.8.7
31) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.0 running Docker 1.0.0
32) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Python 2.7
33) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running PHP 5.5
34) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Node.js
35) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 1.9.3
36) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running PHP 5.4
37) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)
38) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Tomcat 7 Java 6
39) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Python
40) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.1 running Docker 1.0.0
41) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.5 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)
42) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
Select (1 to 42): 1
Select an environment type.
Available environment types are:
1) LoadBalanced
2) SingleInstance
Select (1 to 2): 1
Create an RDS DB Instance? [y/n]: n
Attach an instance profile (current value is "[Create a default instance profile]"):
1) [Create a default instance profile]
2) aws-opsworks-ec2-role.1405096101659
3) aws-opsworks-ec2-role.1405096100907
4) aws-opsworks-ec2-role.1405096100282
5) aws-opsworks-ec2-role.1405096099782
6) aws-opsworks-ec2-role.1405096099019
7) aws-opsworks-ec2-role
8) [Other instance profile]
Select (1 to 8): 
Updated AWS Credential file at "/Users/toli/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file".
```

Got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 21, in <module>
    from aws.dev_tools import * 
  File "/Users/toli/Sites/oselot-blog/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto
ImportError: No module named boto
```

So I actually got boto by doing

1. `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
2. `sudo get-pip.py`
3. `sudo pip install boto`

And it worked...